# Google push-to-deploy jenkins image fails after reboot

Tags: jenkins, docker, google-compute-engine

I am using the most recent jenkins setup from https://cloud.google.com/tools/repo/push-to-deploy in order to CI my development environment codebase. I noticed that the jenkins git plugin in the image provided is out of date and seems to have a bug with regex branch matching. I updated the plugin to the latest version but after that it seems that jenkins will not restart.

Rebooting the server got jenkins back up, but the [google startup script](https://dl.google.com/dl/jenkins/p2dsetup/setup-script.sh) doesn't relaunch and reconnect the docker slave images properly.

Has anyone had this experience and resolved it?

Comment: Do you have a static IP for your Jenkins server or an ephemeral one? IF ephemeral and you did your backup your IP might got changed which might cause the issue.

Comment: The server boots, it is the startup script that fails to take into account the restart scenario. It tries to reinstall docker and create new executors instead of restarting the existing ones.